# JS metaprogramming - get line where function is declared

Tags: javascript, node.js

Normally I could use `new Error().stack` to get a trace of where the runtime path was. However, in my current situation, I can't get at the stack trace, because if I declare `new Error()` it will be in the wrong path.

However, I do have a reference to the function that I want the trace for. All I really want is the line number where the function was declared. Is it possible to get that using some JavaScript metaprogramming facility or is `new Error().stack` the only way?

Here is the code I am talking about:

```
function handleTest(test, cb) {
    function makeCallback(err){
        clearTimeout(timer);
        handleTestResult(err, test);
        cb(null, err);
    }

    var done = _.once(makeCallback);

    try {
        if(!inDebugMode){  //only add timeout if we aren't debugging
            var timer = setTimeout(function () {
                test.timedOut = true;
                done(new Error('timed out'); // the stack trace for this error will not include the info I need
            }, 2000);
        }

        test.cb.apply(self, [function (err) {  //what I really want is the location of the test.cb function, (where test.cb is declared)
             done(err);
        }]);
    }
    catch (err) {  //this err instance on the other hand has a stack trace I can use
        console.log(err.stack);
        done(err);
    }
}
```